# MySQL not inserting record in any table

Tags: mysql

I have a database of aprx. 12 tables. I fully tested the application on my demo server but when I shifted to client's server. No record insertion in client's server in any table.

Can any body help me out that which kind of issue this is.

thanks in advance

Comment: CHeck user rights, check database name, check logs

Comment: have you properly set the database properties?  and please elaborate your problem

Comment: How are you trying to insert records? Has your apllication some error control when it tries to insert records? What error do you get?

Comment: hmm, fully tested?  no error/exception reporting in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Suppose, this should be a rights issue. Check the rights of the current user. You application must be having some logs. Check out the errors and post it here. May be we can then give some insight.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is the permission issue, please provide the insert ,update privileges to your database user.